# Background thread in Rails can't see instance variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to gather up some data from a rails application, aggregate it, and send it off to a remote server periodically.  I instantiate my aggregation class in a global variable (I know, I know) in application.rb.

Inside my aggregation class, I fire up a thread that sleeps for 10 seconds, then looks at the queue, processes the data, and sends it.  The queue is a hash stored in an instance variable of the class.

From the rails controller, I call a method in the aggregator class to queue the data in the hash.  Of course this is on a different thread than the background task that reads the queue.  The problem is that the background task never sees any data in the hash.  In my log, I print out the object_id of the hash both when I write to it (from the controllers thread), and when I read from it (from the background thread).  The hash#object_id matches from both threads, but the background thread never sees the data.

Whats *killing* me is that **this works fine outside of rails**.  I've set up tests with many threads that really pound on it, and it works fine (there is some thread protection that I am not showing for clarity).  Anyone know how the `object_id`'s can match, but the contents are not consistent?

```
class Aggregator

def initialize
  @q = {}
  @timer = nil
end

def start
  @timer = Thread.new do
    loop do
      sleep(10)
      flush_q
    end
  end
end

def flush_q
  logger.debug "flush: q.object_id = #{@q.object_id}"  # matches what I get below
  logger.debug "flush: q.length = #{@q.length}"   # always zero!
  @q.each_pair do |k,v|
    # pack it up and send it
  end
  @q.clear
end

def add(item)
  logger.debug "add: q.object_id = #{@q.object_id}"  # matches what I get above
  @q[item.name] ||= item
  logger.debug "add: q.length = #{@q.length}"   # increases with each add
  # not actually that simple, but not relevant
end

end
```

Comment: How are you calling `start` and `add`?

Comment: 'start' gets called once after I create the single instance of this class.  'add' gets called from a rails controller.

Comment: Well, the first thing I notice is that you don't have any mutex synchronization, meaning that access to the hash isn't controlled across threads, which may be problematic. Where is the Aggregator instance defined?

Comment: Is this in production? If so how is the app deployed?

Comment: @Chris Heald:  Regarding thread safety, I do take care of that, but I left it out for clarity.  In my testing, I'm running it without any load, and it fails consistently.  Regarding the instance, I create it and start it in `application.rb`.  I keep it in a global variable, so that is's available to all controllers.  Better idea?

Comment: @FrederickCheung:  Yes, it's in 'production', deployed via Git at EY.  But it's not live to the world, I'm still debugging it.  It works fine in development locally.  Good question!

Comment: My thought is that perhaps you are starting it, it's timing out after 10 seconds, and *then* your requests happen. Additionally, if you're storing it in a global variable, then that means that it will be available to all your requests. If you want it available to all controllers, it can just be an instance variable defined on ApplicationController.

Comment: @ChrisHeald:  Well, the loop keeps running.  I see the output from flush_q happening right on schedule every 10 seconds.  But the q always appears to be empty to flush_q(), but not empty for add().  Thanks for the tip on ApplicationController.  I'll make that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that your code is deployed using a forking app server (eg unicorn or passenger).

This means that your app is loaded once and then new instances are forked from that master instances. Forking is cheap so this means that new instances of the app can be started up/shutdown really quickly.

I believe that your aggregator instance is getting created/started in this master process. When this forks the process's entire memory space is copied (so there an instance of aggregator in the new process, with the same object id and so on).

However when forking only the current thread is copied , so the aggregator flushing is only happening in the master process, but all the appending is happening in the child processes. You could confirm this by adding `Proccess.pid` to what you log - you should see that your logging is coming from 2 different process.

One way of fixing this would be to start/restart your thread after the child process has forked. How you do this depends on how the app is being served. With unicorn you can do this in your unicorn config via the `after_fork` method. With passenger you do

```
PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
  if forked
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I suspected something like this.  Even the `object_id`s will be the same?  I'll check this right away in the morning.

Comment: Everything will be the same since the entire memory space is copied. The only thing that doesn't copy over is threads.

Comment: That was it.  Got fooled by ASSuming the object ID was a suitable stand-in for memory address.  Did not realize they would stay the same after a fork.  Thanks, Fred!

Comment: Well it is a suitable standing for memory address, but those addresses are for the process's memory space, so they get copied too.

Comment: So I restarted the background thread in response to the fork, and it works sometimes.  But it seems that sometimes the process gets killed before the background loop gets around to reading the buffer.